# Float Point arithmetic in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to modify the second column in a .dat file called "field.dat" by scaling every value in the second column by 1.282700422.  Here is the awk script i have made:

```
#!/bin/bash  
awk '{
    $2=sprintf("%f",$2)*1.282700422
}' field.dat
```

the format of my field.dat file is as follows:

```
0.1500E+01  0.5000E+00  0.5914E+00  0.7693E-04
0.4500E+01  0.5000E+00  0.5911E+00  0.8520E-04
0.7500E+01  0.5000E+00  0.5907E+00  0.9419E-04
0.1050E+02  0.5000E+00  0.5904E+00  0.1039E-03
```

The program seems to run by does not seem to modify the second column.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this:

```
awk '{$2*=1.282700422} 1' field.dat

0.1500E+01 0.64135 0.5914E+00 0.7693E-04
0.4500E+01 0.64135 0.5911E+00 0.8520E-04
0.7500E+01 0.64135 0.5907E+00 0.9419E-04
0.1050E+02 0.64135 0.5904E+00 0.1039E-03
```

That says... *"multiply field2 by 1.282700422 on every line of input, and then do the default thing - which is print the current record - because the condition `1` evaluates to `true`"*

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
awk '{ $2=sprintf("%E",$2*1.282700422); print }' field.dat
```

Also note that awk doesn't modify the file in place, only outputting the changed data to stdout.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to output everything into a new file using ">>"